# RStudio: Unable to establish connection with R session

Tags: rstudio

I have never experienced this before. But today whatever button i click in RStudio, i got the error message box.

**Unable to establish connection with R session**

I got this error message when I try to run code, save files, open new project, open files, install packages, clear workspace, **run code in console**. I uninstall and reinstall again. Also tried to remove Rstudio desktop state, the error will not go away. The same thing happen all over again.

How do I get around this ?